# Using Vue component in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, webpack, vue.js

I have a fresh installation of Laravel 5.3 project which built in with example Vue component.

```
require('./bootstrap');

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

I then tried to add

```
<example></example>
```

in welcome.blade.php, saved it, but nothing changed.

I run gulp watch, too even I didn't change any JS file.

Did I miss something? Or this is not the way Vue component works?

Comment: Does vue print something in javascript console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you include app.js in welcome.blade.php?

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <example></example>
    </div>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

You probably did so, but also be sure to add an element with the id (in this case `#app`) you defined in the options of your Vue instance.

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49664451/how-can-i-add-condition-on-vue-component-that-is-loaded-from-the-view-blade-lara