# How can I add condition on vue component that is loaded from the view blade laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My view blade laravel like this :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    ...
        <transaction></transaction>
    ...
@endsection
@section('modal')
    <transaction-modal/>
@endsection
```

The view blade laravel load two vue component. That are transaction component and transaction modal component. So if the view blade executed, it will run the components

My transaction component like this :

```
<template>
    ...
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-transaction" @click="show(item.id)">View</a>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    ...
    export default {
        ...
        methods: {
            show(id) {
                ....
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My transaction modal like this :

```
<template>
    <div id="modal-transaction" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        ...
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        ...
    }
</script>
```

From the script, the transaction modal component will run if the view blade called. I want the transaction modal run if user click view. If user not click view, the transaction modal component not executed

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you wish to hide the transaction-modal on page load and show it on clicking a button?

Comment: @Markandeya Yes that's what I mean

Comment: You kind of mixing the instantiation of vue components and bootstrap modal trigger. What you can do is using bootstrap modal events

Comment: @anasceym Yes. Seems I use it

Comment: While using bootstrap modals, you should do what @anasceym suggested. As to the what you asked, I hope my answer gives the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing of instantiation of Vue components and Bootstrap's modals event triggered.

What you can do is using Bootstrap modal [events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events). Example code below:

```
<template>
    <div id="modal-transaction" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        ...
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            onModalOpen() {
                // Do something when modal opens
            },
            onModalClose() {
                // Do something when modal closed
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            $('#modal-transaction').on('shown.bs.modal', this.onModalOpen.bind(this))
            $('#modal-transaction').on('hidden.bs.modal', this.onModalClose.bind(this))
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Seems it does not work. Because when the view blade laravel executed, the transaction modal component called. So if the modal open or no. The transaction modal component will executed

Comment: off course it will be called.. you can put the function that should be called only when the modal is opened in onModalOpen()